# Receiving messages and sending messages over NetworkStream to a Client

Tags: c#, tcplistener, networkstream

I have a question about sending and receiving messages from a TCPListener server to a client over a Network Stream in C#. Right now, my TCPListener instance can receive one message from a client and write it to the server console, and it can accept one input string and send it back to the client. But I wish to improve the function to accept multiple consecutive messages from a client and send multiple consecutive responses back to the client. Does anyone happen to have any pointers if the ReadAsync and WriteAsync functions of a NetworkStream can handle receiving multiple consecutive messages or sending multiple consecutive messages and if there is a better method to achieve this? Also, since the Console.ReadLine function will block in the case the server never receives any user input from ReadLine (and no Enter key is pushed), is there a way to test if there's optional user input from the keyboard? That way I could try to execute the send message commands only if the server received some kind of console input from the user, and could continue receiving client messages otherwise.

```
   public static async Task getMessage(TcpListener server)
      {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[256];
            using (var theStream = await server.AcceptTcpClientAsync())
            {
                using (var tcpStream = theStream.GetStream())
                {

                    await tcpStream.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                    var msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
                    Console.WriteLine(msg);
                    var payload = Console.ReadLine();
                    var bytes2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload);
                    await tcpStream.WriteAsync(bytes2, 0, bytes2.Length);
                }

           }

      }
```

Comment: I think people down graded you posting because of the fact you are trying to send back multiple response from server to client which is problematic.  A client is a master and server is a slave.  So normally you would have client send a command, server ack(optional), server process command, server send a response.  If client sends multiple messages than you need to send an ID with each message so the server can respond with the ID so the client knows which response is associated with each command.  You are using two layers of the Network 1) Application Layer 2) TCP Transport Layer.

Comment: Dear @jdweng, TCP is not a request/response-oriented protocol. it is a real two-way asynchronous communication protocol that allows concurrent read/write. If what you said was true, playing a game like PUBG would eat up much more network resources than necessary and would introduce lags. Think of your PUBG client asking continuously for all the movements and actions of all the other players. This is not an efficient way to program the communications for a multi-player, real-time action game. What you said is true for a stateless protocol like HTTP.

Comment: @Oguz Ozgul : I know exactly how TCP operates and been using it for 40 years.  You have to define a Application Layer Protocol. For chat applications, two way async protocol is acceptable.  But two way async should never be used in a command and control application.  The server is a slave.  There are other protocols you can impliment over TCP like Token Ring.  But that is getting more complicated then is needed here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is interesting to see a server implementation dedicated to only one client!

TCP is a two-way communication protocol so yes, you can, of course, send what you want and when you want and receive anything at the same time.

I tried to put comments in the source to let it explain itself.

But the critical point is declaring the `TcpClient` and `NetworkStream` instances as static variables so that the main thread (the thread which reads from the console and sends the payload to the client) can access them

Hope this helps.

```
public static async Task getMessage(TcpListener server)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[256];
    using (theStream = await server.AcceptTcpClientAsync())
    {
        using (tcpStream = theStream.GetStream())
        {
            // We are using an infinite loop which ends when zero bytes have been received.
            // Receiving zero bytes means the transmission is over (client disconnected)
            while (await tcpStream.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length) > 0)
            {
                var msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
                Console.WriteLine(msg);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Client has disconnected");
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Transmists the payload to the client
/// </summary>
/// <param name="payload">The payload to transmit to the client</param>
/// <returns></returns>
static async Task Transmit(string payload)
{
    var bytes2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload);
    await tcpStream.WriteAsync(bytes2, 0, bytes2.Length);
}

// We are declaring the TcpClient and NetworkStream as static variables
// to be able to access them from all the threads.
private static TcpClient theStream;
public static NetworkStream tcpStream;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, 9876);
    server.Start();

    // Start the task getMessage() to accept a client and receive
    Task.Run(() => getMessage(server));

    string payload;
    while ((payload = Console.ReadLine()) != "exit")
    {
        // Check if the client has connected.
        if (tcpStream != null)
        {
            // Check if they are still connected
            if (theStream.Client.Connected)
            {
                Task.Run(() => Transmit(payload));
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("the client connection is lost");
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The client has not connected yet.");
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Stopping the server");
    server.Stop();
}
```